# How to write text to every empty file

Tags: command-line

I can find empty files in current directory with;

```
find . -empty -type f
```

I'd like to know

1. How to write text to empty files which I found.
2. How to empty the files if they already contain text.

Comment: Could you please give an example with some files and what should happen to them? Also please explain why you want to do all that, it doesn't seem useful to me and I find it hard to understand. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @ByteCommander, sorry if im  unclear, wanna achieve to write inside of each empty file which i found for instance "hello"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you asked for a solution to do it using `xargs`:

```
find -empty | xargs -I files sh -c 'echo hello > $1' -- files
```

#### Notes

- We are running a `sh` using `xargs` while passing a file name each time which will be placed instead of `$1`, simply `$1` is the first argument we pass to a script.
- Using `--` I'm telling that `sh` command is done here and at the end I'm passing the file name as an argument to the `sh`.

---

Test:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/lab && cd /tmp/lab
$ touch 1 2 3 && echo foo > 2
$ find -empty
./1
./3
```

```
$ find -empty | xargs -I files sh -c 'echo hello > $1' -- files
$ cat 1 2 3
hello
foo
hello
```

Comment: could you tell  this part pls ? "sh -c 'echo hello > $@  ' -- files" thanks @Ravexina

Comment: Updated the answer ...

Comment: really thanks  i m making you tired with questions

Comment: @solfish you're welcome, it's fine ;) see my updates again ...

Answer (score 3):

I believe this should work:

```
find . -empty -type f -exec bash -c "echo 'hello' >  {}" \;
```

Update to find empty files and then write to them and also find non-empty files and empty them:

```
find . -type f \( -empty -o -size +0b \) -exec bash -c "if [[ ! -s '{}' ]]; then echo 'hello' > '{}'; else cp /dev/null '{}'; fi" \;
```

Note:

This is run from the target folder, if not then just add the path to the command like so:

```
find /path/to/folder ...
```

Comment: why use bash -c in there @George?

Comment: can i use xargs ? how?

Comment: See `man bash`: `-c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.  If  there  are  arguments
                 after the command_string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.
`

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a shell loop...

First, to make globbing recursive to mirror the action of `find`, turn on globstar

```
shopt -s globstar
```

Then find the files

```
for f in **; do [[ -f "$f" ]] && [[ ! -s "$f" ]] && echo "$f"; done
```

You will see all the empty files. The `-s` condition of `test` means the file is longer than 0 bytes. Using `! -s` you can find files of zero length. `-f` checks the file is a regular file.

Now make a slight adjustment to the command to write to the files:

```
for f in **; do [[ -f "$f" ]] && [[ ! -s "$f" ]] && echo "hello" > "$f"; done
```

You also said you want to know how to empty the files if they are not empty. The simplest way to empty a file is to truncate it with redirection

```
> foo
```

empties `foo` of any content (or creates empty file `foo` if it does not exist). So, to empty files that contain text **(please be aware that this will destroy data in files; make sure you are running this command in the correct directory)** you can use:

```
for f in **; do [[ -f "$f" ]] && if [[ -s "$f" ]] && > "$f"; done
```

You can combine the two commands, to write to files that are empty, and empty files that contain text:

```
for f in **; do [[ -f "$f" ]] && if [[ ! -s "$f" ]]; then echo "hello" > "$f"; else > "$f"; fi; done
```

or more readably **(please check the current directory first - this destroys data in files)**:

```
for f in **; do 
  [[ -f "$f" ]] && if 
    [[ ! -s "$f" ]]; then echo "hello" > "$f"
    else > "$f"
  fi
done
```

This means "for all the files in this directory and its subdirectories, test whether the file is a regular file, and if it is, then if it is empty, write "hello" in it, and if it is not empty, then empty it".

You can turn off globstar when done if you want (but it will be unset anyway when you start a new shell, for example by opening a new terminal, typing `bash` or switching user):

```
shopt -u globstar
```

Comment: what is shopt - u globstar your explanation, what changes if not use on script @Zanna?

Comment: it turns off globstar, so globbing with `**` no longer expands to all files including subdirectories & their contents @solfish

Comment: so , if on status i can reach every file , off status not, right?

Comment: that's right @solfish - that's why I set it at the start of my answer, so that globbing will behave like `find` and recurse into subdirectories

Comment: hımm , and it is just useful with '**' to find files and directiories, i think @Zanna?

Comment: BTW, thanks so, i learned something new today @Zanna.

Comment: @solfish the `*` character is expanded by the shell. On its own it will expand to all non-hidden files (another shell option allows matching hidden files too). Normally `**` is the same as `*` but when you set `globstar` it means all files in this directory and its subdirectories recursively (directories are also files). So, it's useful when you want to manipulate files in subdirectories of the current working directory using the shell for any reason. I hope that is an enlightening description, but you can read [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) if not!

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand the question, could you be more specific?
If you want to write some text/code in a file, Vim works really well.

```
vim [File Path]
```

e.g.

```
vim /etc/hosts
```

Comment: no, i dont mean it, after finding all empty files i d like to write all inside same script/text